# Various PEM to DER in perl

Tags: perl, openssl

i have application with client-server architecture.

client (C program):

1. generate various DER encoded data
2. convert DER to PEM (using openssl's PEM_write_bio) with various PEM header
3. send PEM to server

server (Perl script):

1. receive PEM data
2. convert PEM to DER
3. ....

My question is how to convert various PEM data to DER/BER (binary data) in perl?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can strip off the PEM tags yourself, and do a decode of the Base64 block inside using [`MIME::Base64`](http://p3rl.org/MIME::Base64).

Should be as simple as

```
$derBlob = decode_base64($base64Blob);
```

Answer (score 3):

An example based on the accepted answer:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use MIME::Base64;

my $certPath = 'cert.pem';

open my $fh, '<', $certPath or die(sprintf('Could not open %s file: %s', $certPath, $!));
my $derBlob = do { local $/; decode_base64(<$fh> =~ s/^-.*?\n//gmr); };
close($fh);
print $derBlob;

1;
__END__
```